# How can I obtain the WLAN ISP name in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, wifi

Fellow overflowers,

I am developing an **iOS application** using the latest **SDK (11.2)** and **Swift 4**.

I am looking for a way to obtain the **WLAN ISP** name.

(for example, my ISP at home is called **NET1 Ltd.**)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, @vadian, I am developing an app with the latest SDK (iOS 11.2). Swift 4 is selected as a language version.

Comment: So you want the ISP name of the network the user is connected to?

Comment: That's correct, @CodeDifferent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTCarrier` will only return carrier info if your iOS device has a SIM card. A better way to obtain it is via an webservice like [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/developers). Here's an example in Playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Foundation

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let url = URL(string: "https://ipinfo.io/org")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else { print(error!); return }
    guard let data = data else { print("Empty data"); return }

    if let ispName = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(ispName)
    } else {
        print("Can't obtain ISP name")
    }
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Core WLAN](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corewlan) framework provides APIs for querying AirPort interfaces and choosing networks.

[Core Telephony](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony) framework provides information about a user’s cellular service provider. You can use [CTCarrier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/ctcarrier) class to obtain information about the user’s home cellular service provider.

Comment: Hi, @Rocky, it is my mistake I did not specify the platform I am developing for. I am making an iOS application where CoreWLAN is not available. I am using **CTCarrier** to obtain some information about WWAN which is the cellular network. Thanks!